# Foreign Key reference in mySQL

Tags: mysql

In mySQL if I created two tables and on table contains a foreign key referenced to the other table. I have entered data in the other table and for the defined foreign key in that as well. Is there any way for the foreign key to automatically update in the second table without having to type in the entire data?
For example I have a customer table which has 2 fields- customerID and customerName. Another table is say a invoice table which has 3 fields- invoiceID, cost and customerID, where customerID is foreign key. So if I enter data in customer table and invoice table as the number of customers are very large I do not want to keep on entering the customerID in the invoice table. As customerID is a foreign key in the other table, how do I make it automatically reference it from customer table?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the customer name in invoice data and customer data already populated, you could do

```
INSERT INTO tbl_invoice (invoiceData, invoiceData2, customerID)
  SELECT 'value1', 'value2', customer.customerID
  FROM tbl_customer customer
  WHERE customer.customerName = 'customer name'
```

So you wouldn't need to deal with customer ids directly.

There is no automatic feature in MySQL to do exactly this. A trigger could be used for it if needed.

Comment: this isn't safe, name attribute can never be primary key and used in an operation like this.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan so are you saying it isn't safe or it cannot be done? If you're saying it isn't safe as there can be multiple customers with same name, I agree. That's something to be thought about by OP. If you're saying it cannot be done, that's wrong.

Comment: you're right, but we agree it's error prone. suggesting something to a starter (as I guess), please let's be more cautious.

Comment: I think with a customer table that only has two fields, customer id + customer name, there is already this issue. I don't see any way of distinguishing between customers with the same name. If there would be more information in the customer table, all the same information could be added to this query, too, so fundamentally it's a limitation of the customer table.

Comment: Sorry about that...I was unclear about the fields. There will be more fields like lastName, address etc.I just wasn't sure how the referencing would work..I used Access before mySQL and it automatically takes in the values of foreign key from the original table so I was wondering if there was any similar feature..Thanks...

Comment: @user2303935 simple answer: no, there isn't. Added as part of my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically add a predefined number, like 1, but that will assign all invoices to customer#1.

On the other hand, you can add customers automatically while adding invoices. For that, you need to control the customerID and if a customer with the given ID is not present, insert a new customer to the customer table with empty name. After that, you still need to enter names for those customers, but not by one and that would get things (maybe) easier.

I think you have a misleading idea here. I strongly suggest reading a book or seeing a tutorial online or examining an example project's database tables.